# Extension method to check if an object is sub class of T

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.5

I am trying to write an extension method that checks if an object is sub class of T.

Here is what I did, but not accepted by visual studio.

```
public static bool IsChildOf<T>(this object obj)
{
    return (typeof(obj).IsSubclassOf(typeof(T)));
}

[Test()]
public void IsChildOfTest()
{
    var dog = new Dog();
    var isAnimal = dog.IsChildOf<Animal>();
    Assert.That(isAnimal);
}
```

Any idea how can i write this?

Comment: Side note: "child class " and "parent class" terms are discouraged. You should say "derived from" instead. A car isn't a child of a vehicle; a car derives from a vehicle. I would name your method "DerivesFrom<T>" instead.

Comment: I agree. Reserve the child/parent terms for "has a" relationships rather than "is a" relationships. Particularly in lists or recursive relationships like trees.

Comment: Comments: `typeof(X)` requires `X` to be a type (like your `T`), not a value or expression (like your `obj`). Are you aware that `IsSubclassOf` is false if one of the types is an interface or a value type, and if the two classes are identical? Maybe you wanted `IsAssignableFrom`? It is probably easier, though, to use the C# keyword `is`. See weston's answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just use `is`. **But note** that `is` doesn't do exactly the same as `IsSubclassOf`. See Jeppe's excellent comment for details and I have an example below too.

On a side note, I don't think Java allows the equivalent `instanceof` in such a generic case for some reason, but it's OK in C#. I.e.:

```
public static bool IsChildOf<T>(this object obj)
{
    return obj is T;
}
```

Then this makes it so trivial that it's more confusing to readers to use an extension method than `is` directly. If you used it directly your test would then look like:

```
[Test()]
public void IsChildOfTest()
{
    var dog = new Dog();
    var isAnimal = dog is Animal;
    Assert.That(isAnimal);
}
```

An example of one of the differences between `is` and `IsSubclassOf`:

```
[Test]
public void IsChildOfTest()
{
    var dog = new Dog();
    Assert.False(dog.GetType().IsSubclassOf(typeof(Dog)));
    Assert.True(dog is Dog);
}
```

Comment: Upvoted for mentioning `is`. It is not exactly equivalent to `Type.IsSubclassOf`. Some differences: If `T` is the *same* class as the run-time type of `obj`, `is` says `true` and `IsSubclassOf` says `false`. If `T` is an interface, `is` checks if `obj` represents that `interface` while `IsSubclassOf` just says `false`. If the run-time type of `obj` is a (boxed) value type, `is` checks as expected while `IsSubclassOf` just says no. `is` also considers co- and contravariance in generics, for example something that is `IEnumerable<string>` is also `IEnumerable<object>` (see `IEnumerable<out T>`).

Comment: @Jeppe Stig Nielsen, very good point that it's not equivalent. Good to make this clear in case of misunderstandings. And indeed, despite the proposed name IsChildOf, the OP may not intend these distinctions.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Thanks, that's a lot of important info I missed off! I guess `is` is equivalent to `Type.IsAssignableFrom`

Comment: I think that is correct, `IsAssignableFrom`. However, if you use `is` you can get a nice compile-time warning if the truth value is obvious. For example `void M(Exception e) { bool here = e is string; }` or `void M(int i) { bool here = i is IFormattable; }`.

Answer (score 6):

Use [`GetType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype.aspx) instead of `typeof` when you have an instance of the type:

```
public static bool IsChildOf<T>(this object obj)
{
    return (obj.GetType().IsSubclassOf(typeof(T)));
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
public static Boolean IsChildOf<T>(this Object obj)
{
   // Don't forget to handle obj == null.
   return obj.GetType().IsSubclassOf(typeof(T));
}
```

Comment: The simple expression `obj is T` does not explode if `obj` is `null` (it just evaluates to `false`). See other advantages of `is` in my comment to weston's answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static bool IsChildOf<T>(this object obj)
    {
        return obj != null && (obj.GetType().IsSubclassOf(typeof(T)));
    }
```

also use `Assert.IsTrue` in place of `Assert.That`